# to change status of services of pc by using create python code

Tags: python, service, module, status

suppose in laptop we start,stop windows services(background app that is working) just like this i have to create a pythone code that first check status of service(app) if it is in start status change into stop status and vice versa.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fueUt.png)

i am trying using win32service module in python[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kplX7.png)

Comment: Please post as text not screenshot.